SiMCOM7600 can't connect MQTT(S) AWS IOT CORE +CMQTTCONNECT: 0 , 34
+CCERTLIST: "cacert.pem"
+CCERTLIST: "cert.pem"
+CCERTLIST: "keycert.pem"

OK
AT+CSSLCFG="sslversion",0,4 

OK
AT+CSSLCFG="authmode",0,2 

OK
AT+CMQTTSTART 

+CMQTTSTART: 23

ERROR
AT+CMQTTREL=0

OK
AT+CMQTTSTOP

+CMQTTSTOP: 0

OK

+CMQTTNONET
AT+CMQTTSTART 

+CMQTTSTART: 0
OK
AT+CMQTTACCQ=0,"SIMCom_client01",1

OK
AT+CMQTTSSLCFG=0,0  

OK
AT+CMQTTWILLTOPIC=0,31

>aws/things/simcom7600_device01/
OK
AT+CMQTTWILLMSG=0,17,1

>SIMCom Connected!
OK
AT+CMQTTSUBTOPIC=0,31,1  

+CMQTTSUBTOPIC: 0,11

ERROR
AT+CMQTTCONNECT=0,"tcp://a35yvcm9b5qfq9-ats.iot.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com:8883",60,1

OK

+CMQTTCONNECT: 0,34



I tried to reset simcom 7600 and not work
I can't connect with aws iot core how to fix this? i add certificate already in tera term and re-upload cert many many time but alway error +CMQTTCONNECT: 0 ,34 and +CMQTTCONNECT: 0 ,26
SIMCOM7600
ARDUINO MKR ZERO

Sorry, but your question is unclear. For tips on asking a good question, please see: How do I ask a good question?

The first error at AT+CMQTTSTART, it returns +CMQTTSTART: 23, did you open a network socket (AT+NETOPEN) before all those command?
